# Separating test suites in Behat

Tags: php, behat, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to reproduce isolated test suites with Behat like I have with Cucumber. I've been trying to tweak the behat.yml file using suites and paths as well as moving files and folders around. Behat results make so little sense that I am starting to conclude that it was not designed with this in mind at all. And the documentation does not describe expected files & folder layouts

For each test suite I want:

- a specific xxx.feature file
- a specific xxxContext.php file, defining a its own `xxxContext` class

I don't want a monolithic FeatureContext.php file. My project is so huge that it would become a nightmare to maintain, not to mention the potential collateral damage between steps. It's OK to have a single behat.yml file if that helps.

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377898/step-definitions-in-external-files-in-behat) but I still haven't solved the problem. How I can create isolated test suites with Behat?

Note: I am using behat 3.0-dev

---

Edit: Here is the "best" I could achieve. I have two suites, one called "OAuth2" and another called "Achievements".

**beyat.yml:**

```
default:
    suites:
        OAuth2:
            contexts:
                - OAuth2Context
        Achievements:
            contexts:
                - AchievementsContext
```

**File hierarchy:**

```
├── behat.yml
└── features
    ├── Achievements.feature
    ├── OAuth2.feature
    └── bootstrap
        └── OAuth2Context.php  <-- Contains the OAuth2Context and AchievementsContext classes. Also, classes are found only if I name this file this way, I don't know why.
```

My main problem is that when I run behat, it complains that there are missing steps. Basically, the OAuth2Context class is missing steps that were defined in Achievements and the AchievementsContext is missing steps that were defined in OAuth2. This output completely baffles me:

```
--- OAuth2Context has missing steps. Define them with these snippets:

    /**
     * @When I say yes
     */
    public function iSayYes()
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @Then you say no
     */
    public function youSayNo()
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

--- AchievementsContext has missing steps. Define them with these snippets:

    /**
     * @When I ask for an Access Token with my credentials
     */
    public function iAskForAnAccessTokenWithMyCredentials2()
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @Then I receive an Access Token
     */
    public function iReceiveAnAccessToken2()
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @When I ask for an Access Token with a Partner User grant type where:
     */
    public function iAskForAnAccessTokenWithAPartnerUserGrantTypeWhere(TableNode $table)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

I believe that this is because I defined two separate classes in the php file. But I really don't want to make a single monolitic class. In fact, I'd even like two separate PHP files. The Classes are defined this way:

```
class OAuth2Context implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
...
    /**
     * @When I ask for an Access Token with my credentials
     */
    public function iAskForAnAccessTokenWithMyCredentials()
    {
    ...
    }
...
}

class AchievementsContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
...
    /**
     * @When I say yes
     */
    public function iSayYes()
    {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Other (smaller) issue is that I have to name my php file OAuth2Context.php  instead of FeatureContext.php, otherwise the classes are not found at all. I don't understand this, as it was my understanding that FeatureContext.php was behat's default name.

---

Edit: SOLUTION, thanks to **Jakub Zalas** :

Here is the file layout that works:

```
├── behat.yml
└── features
    ├── achievements
    │   └── Achievements.feature
    ├── bootstrap
    │   ├── AchievementsContext.php  <-- AchievementsContext class
    │   └── OAuth2Context.php        <-- OAuth2Context class
    └── oauth
        └── OAuth2.feature
```

With the following **beyat.yml** file:

```
default:
    suites:
        OAuth2:
            contexts:
                - OAuth2Context
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/oauth ]
        Achievements:
            contexts:
                - AchievementsContext
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/achievements ]
```

This way I have steps in separated PHP files, which was my main requirement, and separated suites with separated feature files. I am a happy camper!

Comment: What you're trying to do is very simple in Behat. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I edited my original post and added as much details as I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you currently organised your suites each feature file will be run for each suite.

Use [filters](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html#suite-filters) or [paths](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/5.suites.html#suite-paths) to define which feature files should match a given suite:

```
# behat.yml

default:
    suites:
        OAuth2:
            contexts:
                - OAuth2Context
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/oauth ]
        Achievements:
            contexts:
                - AchievementsContext
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/achievements ]
```

Having a single feature file per suite is probably not worth it, as you'll end up with lots of suites without a real benefit. Better group features in slightly bigger suites, and register multiple contexts per suite.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked great after changing the files layout. I edited my original post to described the solution. Thanks!